# jquery plugin scrollTo not working

Tags: jquery, scrollto

I'm trying to use Ariel Flesler's jquery scrollTo plugin for horizontal scrolling, but can't get the scrolling working (the plugin and jquery are included in the head). Here's the relevent HTML:

```js
<div id="main-content">
  <div id="quiz-wrapper">

    <div class="quiz" id="question-first">
      <h5 class="quiz-question">What is the capital of X?</h5>
      <div class="quiz-answer"><a
          title="$(...).scrollTo( '#share-first', 800 );" href="#">Answer</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="quiz" id="share-first">
      <div class="points-message"> 
         <h3>+75 for every Tweet and Like</h3>
      </div>                
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The relevant styling:

```css
div#main-content {
  width: 570px;
}

div#quiz-wrapper {
  width: 3000px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.quiz {
  width: 520px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  float: left;
}
```

Here's the link to the plugin: http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html. Any idea what's wrong with the scrollTo call?

Comment: Are you getting a javascript error? What exactly do you mean by 'not working'? Is `$(...)` your literal jQuery selector? I've also never seen javascript included in the `title` attribute. If you want to know that it is firing, put an alert in there instead.

Comment: Ah, stupid error... thanks for pointing out the title note - switched that to onclick and it started scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tried to apply javascripting into the `title` attribute. You probably intended to apply it to the `onclick` attribute.